# Can Hume’s views on induction and on miracles be reconciled?

Tags: epistemology, hume

Here's a summary of his conclusion about induction.

> Thus not only our reason fails us in the discovery of the ultimate connexion of causes and effects, but even after experience has inform'd us of their constant conjunction, 'tis impossible for us to satisfy ourselves by our reason, why we shou'd extend that experience beyond those particular instances… . We suppose, but are never able to prove, that there must be a resemblance betwixt those objects, of which we have had experience, and those which lie beyond the reach of our discovery. *A Treatise of Human Nature* 1.3.6.11, 1739-40

... and a summary of his argument against miracles.

> …. A miracle is a violation of the laws of nature; and as a firm and unalterable experience has established these laws, the proof against a miracle, from the very nature of the fact, is as entire as any argument from experience can possibly be imagined. Why is it more than probable, that all men must die;….; unless it be, that these events are found agreeable to the laws of nature, and there is required a violation of these laws, or in other words, a miracle to prevent them? …. It is no miracle that a man, seemingly in good health, should die on a sudden…. . But it is a miracle, that a dead man should come to life; because that has never been observed in any age or country. There must, therefore, be a uniform experience against every miraculous event, otherwise the event would not merit that appellation. And as a uniform experience amounts to a proof, there is here a direct and full proof, from the nature of the fact, against the existence of any miracle;…. *An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding* 1.10.1.90, 1748

I don't see how these views can be reconciled.

Comment: "Even after *experience has inform'd us* of their constant conjunction, 'tis impossible for us to satisfy ourselves *by our reason*... And as a *uniform experience* amounts to a proof, there is here a direct and full proof, from the nature of the fact, against the existence of any miracle". Reason cannot be satisfied with just about anything, but experience provides an argument against miracles "as entire as any argument from experience can possibly be". What is there in need of reconciliation?

Comment: @Ludwig V. I agree. Hume should have explained this.  Is there any passage where he does so?

Comment: This is an excellent question. Given Hume's views on empirical knowledge, his views on miracles degenerates into the observation that people are led by their mental faculties to expect miracles to be impossible--which is, of course, exactly what makes it a miracle.

Comment: @conifold Yes, but in his discussion of induction (though I realize that he never uses that term), he is very clear about what proofs experience can and cannot provide. Hume assumes that our experience to date does not provide support for miracles. But that does not prove anything about miracles in the future. But that is exactly what he is trying to persuade us of in this passage.  True, he is talking about probabilities here, but his argument applies to any probability of miracles that we find in our past experience. Full disclosure - I think Hume's miracles argument is a very persuasive.

Comment: @David Gudeman
 Thanks for the compliment. You comment is an interesting move, but I'm not clear what conclusion you might draw from it.

Comment: Hume only argues that experience to date does not prove anything about miracles (or anything else) in the future *as far as reason is concerned*. But he is an empiricist, not a rationalist - so much the worse for the reason. If its standard of "proof" cannot be met we better find something else to inform us. The real force of proof is to move us to act upon what is proved, and for that experience is proof enough, for it already engages the passions. "*Reason is, and ought only to be the slave of the passions, and can never pretend to any other office than to serve and obey them.*"

Comment: @conifold You are right, and he turns to experience. From experience, he says, we can find resemblance, contiguity and constant conjunction. But not anything that would justify predictions. He recognizes that we nonetheless make predictions and attributes this to custom. Which _proves_ nothing. In _Enquiry_ V.2 He offers a justification for this habit, that it is useful. He cannot prove that, of course, so I'm not sure what to make of it. The question remains, however, whether he is justified in using the word "proof" in the miracles argument.

Comment: @David Gudeman One of my problems about this argument is that the empirical evidence is that not everyone is led by their previous experience to doubt the possibility of miracles, though he clearly thinks that they **should** be. Another is how people might be led to believe in any rare event (cf. lottery paradox).  The whole argument is beginning to seem to be fraught with difficulties - which is progress of a sort, I suppose.

Comment: The question does not remain, not for Hume, for the sum total of his arguments is that we ought to reject the high minded notion of proof and justification as largely useless. And transfer the word "proof" to a more useful concept. Kant's later attempt to save the loftier sense of proof did not work out, and today we have the essentially Humean pragmatic concept outside of mathematics. Hence his argument against miracles is just of the sort we call "proof" today (not that it is not open to criticism on other grounds, e.g. Bayesian).

Comment: @conifold Certainly, Hume abandons proof and justification so far as causality is concerned. He also explains why we in fact tend to develop expectations - custom or habit, in a word. But I don't think he suggests that it is a *replacement* for the concept of proof. Which is why I don't understand what he means when he says that uniform experience amounts to a proof.

Comment: Hume suggests it as the replacement exactly when he says that uniform experience amounts to a proof, as well as in many other places. "*Analogies and resemblances*” are the “*sole proofs of the Copernican system*" in Dialogues. Indeed, in light of critique of causality, no empirical prediction can be "proved" in the rationalist sense. And yet, experimental proofs abound in Newtonian physics, of which Hume was of such a high opinion that he strove to become the Newton of psychology. Only relations of ideas warrant rationalist proofs, when matters of fact are involved the meaning is replaced.

Comment: @Conifold I'm beginning to see how it might be possible to understand this _via_ the idea of custom and habit. But I still don't understand how it might work to justify an experimental effort without the idea of uniformity of nature.

Comment: Uniformity of nature rests on the same basis as what it is supposed to justify, what does not suffice without it cannot suffice with it either. It is merely a label, like "dormitive virtue" in 'explaining' why opium puts us to sleep. "*If Reason determin’d us, it would proceed upon that principle...*" The thing is, Reason does not determine us, the "*other principle of equal weight and authority*" does. And it suffices, for proof and much else.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you tell me where the quotations come from? I would like to look them up in context.

Comment: @conifold Perhaps I should have included your name in my last post, so you would be told about it. Sorry. Unless I can look up those quotations and read them in context, I can't comment. But you (as different from Hume) say that experience suffices for proof. It would seem that you think that reason and experience are different things that can do the same work. For me, even if they have equal weight and authority (whatever that means), they do different things and ideally work together. For example, reason proves things, experience provides the facts that are evidence.

Comment: Treatise 1.3.6.4 and Enquiry 5.1.2. But I do not think the work is the same, just as the meaning of "proof" is not in different contexts. To each its own. And it's not like reason has no place in experimental proofs, ideas need to be related there too, it just does not *determine* what counts as proof anymore. The ideal you speak of is not one that Hume shared, "*Reason is, and ought only to be the slave of the passions...*"

Comment: Reason has its place in experimental proofs. So does experience. I'm afraid that on my understanding of proof, whatever counts as proof is rational, because reason includes a quasi-ethical obligation to accept its results. That means that it is possible not to. The same is not true of experience - its effects (without the involvement of reason) are effectively causal. Or so it seems to me.

Comment: @conifold Let's move this discussion to chat. We'll be forced to do so soon anyway. You'll find a link at the end of the comments on the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are encouraged to answer our own questions and to share our research. So I would like to share my thoughts on the question after the very helpful discussion of it.

When I asked the question, I quoted from *A Treatise of Human Nature*. In this answer, I have restricted myself to *An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding* because one can expect the *Enquiry* to be self-consistent and there is no need to get involved in assessing the differences between the two for the purposes of the question.

**Hume's project**

Hume summarizes his project in the final section of the book (Section 12 *Of the Academical or Sceptical Philosophy*). It is to identify the proper scope of human knowledge and get rid whatever is useless. This means we should “commit to the flames” any volume of divinity or school metaphysics that does not contain either "abstract discussion of mathematics (quantity or number)" or "of matter of fact and existence".

Which seems clear enough, if a bit radical. Divinity and metaphysics are condemned because they try to extend the scope of human reason beyond what it can do. It gives rise to excessive scepticism and vacuous ideas with no basis in experience. Some divinity gets a pass because “It has a foundation in reason, so far as it is supported by experience.” “But” he continues “its best and most solid foundation is faith and divine revelation.” (Section 12.3). However, his critique of reason does allow for a role for reason, with limitations.

He explains the project in a different way in the body of the section, where he distinguishes between Pyrrhonism or excessive scepticism and what he calls mitigated scepticism.

Excessive scepticism is the philosophical scepticism we are familiar with from Descartes and Berkeley. Hume believes that it is difficult, if not impossible, to refute. His main objection is that no lasting good can come of it, and he prescribes “action, and employment, and the occupations of common life” as a cure. This respect for common life shows at several points in his philosophy.

Mitigated scepticism is characterized in two ways. Part of proper thinking, he says, is “a degree of doubt, and caution, and modesty …, in all kinds of scrutiny and decision.” The other characterization is the result of Pyrrhonian scepticism. It is “the limitation of our enquiries to such subjects as are best adapted to the narrow capacity of human understanding.” (Section 12.3)

**The problem**

In Section 10.1 *Of Miracles* Hume offers “uniform experience” as “proof, full and entire” for his proposition that miracles are impossible. How does he get that from his argument against induction in Section 4 *Sceptical Doubts Concerning the Operations of the Understanding*?

**Proof**

In Section 4, he presses home the key point that experience in the past cannot be extended to cover experiences in the future, or indeed any experiences not yet known. In Section 5 *Sceptical Solution of these Doubts* he does not abandon empirical generalizations but argues that they are customs or habits, arising from the imagination, which calls up the idea of the effect when the idea of the cause is presented; he calls this the association of ideas. He argues that this is a good thing, because it is useful. He also claims (in Section 5.2) that “we find (sc. have found in the past) a pre-established harmony between the course of nature and the succession of our ideas”. All this runs up against the sceptical objection of course, but this isn’t about what is rational. It is about what we do.

In a footnote to the title of Section 6 *Of Probability* Hume cites Locke’s distinction between “demonstrative” and “probable” arguments; Hume objects that this means that it is only probable that everyone must die. He proposes that we classify arguments as demonstrations, proofs and probabilities. “By proofs meaning such arguments from experience as leave no room for doubt or opposition.”

So he does explain to the attentive reader how he will use the term ‘proof' in future. One might object that the aim of proof is justification of belief, while an account of the mechanism that generates belief is not, or not necessarily, a justification of belief. So it seems odd to suggest that his account of the genesis of customs or habits is a justification of them. But presenting evidence will cause belief, so the aim of proof is achieved. In practice, this will mean that “uniform experience” will amount to a proof.
The ruling out of doubt or opposition is rather surprising, but it is hard to argue with the examples he offers later in the same section – “Fire has always burned, and water suffocated every human creature: The production of motion by impulse and gravity is an universal law, which has hitherto admitted of no exception.” (Section 6)

He seems in no doubt that he has succeeded in resolving the sceptical doubts, but without directly refuting excessive scepticism; that would certainly explain the odd title of Section 5 - Sceptical Solution of these Doubts. So the difference between his discussion of induction and “custom or habit” in Section 5 and his presentation of the argument against miracles in Section 10 is really just a change in emphasis and presentation.

**Miracles**

Hume tells us that “A miracle may be accurately defined, a transgression of a law of nature by a particular volition of the Deity, or by the interposition of some invisible agent.” (Footnote in Section 10.1) His long argument against the testimony for miracles culminates in his argument that because a miracle is defined as a violation of the laws of nature, which are established by “firm and unalterable experience”, they are impossible.

Knock-down arguments are very satisfying, but they are rare and I am suspicious of them. In my view this argument is very narrow and over-simplified. Hume does recognize some of the complications, but not all. To understand the topic a wider view is required. But that is beyond my scope.

He even applies his argument to the miracle of the resurrection of Jesus Christ and then declares that the real foundation of belief in that miracle is not reason, or even custom and experience. It is faith. He further says that faith is itself a miracle. So there is no more to be said. It seems that the real point of the section is to show, not only another limitation of reason, but also of custom and experience.

The appeal to faith is a surprise. There is no hint of it Section 4 or 5. On the other hand, it is not exactly incompatible with those Sections 4 and 5.

Hume is following the same strategy in his discussion of induction and of miracles and he is consistent in that. Start with an argument of excessive scepticism, separate what needs to be saved and what must be let go, and find an alternative justification for what needs to be saved. So the argument against causation is allowed to run its course; then an alternative foundation – experience - is found for empirical generalizations and the pre-established harmony between the course of nature and the succession of our ideas” justifies him referring to natural laws that are objectively true. In the same way, the argument against miracles is pressed to the end, at which point, faith saves at least the two miracles that are critical for him.

Comment: In other words, Hume deems Pyrrhonian scepticism and scepticism about induction impractical (even though he's famous today for buoying the latter), and the latter's empirical generalizations convinces as readily as anything that should, to the detriment of alleged miracles such generalizations would contradict.

Comment: @J.G. Yes. Complications. He does have a reputation for buoying scepticism about induction. But he thinks he has solved the problem of induction, by providing something that will do anything that a rational method would. Maybe his solution untenable, but I would like to know why. So his reputation is only half the story.

Comment: @J.G. In the same way, his promotion of the argument against miracles is not what it seems. He presses the argument against some "miracles". But when it comes to the resurrection, faith rescues from his own scepticism. No wonder he thinks that faith irself is a miracle. Note that there's no room for argument about it. I think this is exactly what Wittgenstein had in mind when he wrote that philosophy is a conjuring trick.

Comment: I think Wittgenstein may have been meant something else, but it's funny how a close reading can suggest Hume was a fideist while contemporaneous readers and later scholars have mulled whether he was an atheist. I think one issue here is when he says "X isn't A-resoluble but is B-resoluble" (making his ideas closer to the contextualism my answer discusses than I gave him credit for), later philosophers had their own opinions about which Xs they'll settle for being B-resoluble. So "Hume" became shorthand for "none are A-resoluble", then e.g. Russell agreed on miracles but not on induction.

Comment: @J.G. I knew he was accused of being an atheist in his own time, but decided to read the text as it stands. But I think it is unfair to get too suspicious of people who may be conforming without enthusiasm but also without scepticism. We all do it in one way or another, in order to get along. I like your diagnosis of why orthodoxy doesn't seem to recognize what Hume was trying to do. I gather that there's a similar issue about Berkeley who also thought he was solving scepticism. No-one really pays any attention to Descartes' route out of scepticism, either.

Comment: It's not so much people being suspicious of him as using "Hume" as shorthand for whichever arguments/positions of his they're accepting or critiquing as opposed to ignoring. Any defence of faith you found in Hume is ignored because, unlike his criticism of miracles, it's not inventive enough to add to the summarized history of the discussion. I wouldn't generalize what I said to Berkeley or Descartes; their routes out of scepticism are found wanting due to the ontologies they devise.

Comment: Well, I can understand using "Hume" as shorthand. For me, the problem with the concept of faith is that it stops any prospect of any discussion that I could recognize as philosophical and Hume doesn't discuss it at all. That's what it is meant to do. But it led me to think about the paradox that if you have faith in one religion it is very hard to be tolerant of any other. You can see this at work in this chapter. His discussion of testimony becomes pretty much unacceptable today. It's a problem. I'll have to read Locke next, I think.

Comment: Hume's defence of skeptics' targets as necessary is refined in later philosophy with not all targets equal; he didn't anticipate this. We can't form the beliefs we need without causation, induction etc.; most philosophers say theism isn't so needed, while [some argue it is to justify theism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reformed_epistemology). There's a modern debate as to whether moral norms are e.g. deliberatively indispensable.

Comment: @J.G. Oh dear. Your comment is going a bit too fast for me. I don't understand the first sentence. I followed the link in the second, but that topic seems to be for people who already believe in God. And again, I don't understand the third sentence. I suggest if you want to pursue this, we should adjourn to the chat room we used before. It's still open. I'm sorry to be so useless. You've obviously read a great deal more than I have.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a modern take on reconciling them that I can't promise is rooted in anything Hume himself clarified for the benefit of any reader who might critique him as you have.

On the one hand, Hume argues he can't know of natural laws; on the other hand, he takes them for granted in critiquing miracles. You could just as easily chastise him elsewhere because, on the one hand, he argues he can't know of causation, but on the other hand he takes it for granted in critiquing free will. (His argument against knowledge of causation is completely different from the one against inductively derived natural laws; it's worth a read.)

To both of these objections, we can present an answer called [*epistemic contextualism*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/contextualism-epistemology). The basic idea is there are multiple types of knowledge. Consider skeptical syllogisms of the form

P1. I don't know not-*h*

P2. If I don't know not-*h*, I don't know *p*

C. I don't know *p*

Now let's admit "know" may be ambiguous:

P1. I don't A-know not-*h*

P2. If I don't B-know not-*h*, I don't C-know *p*

C. I don't D-know *p*

This syllogism is only valid if A is B and C is D, and how plausible P2 is depends on the choices of B, C, and may even require B to be C. This is how you can respond to people who say "you don't know you have hands because you don't know you're not a brain in a vat". You don't have were-it-otherwise-I'd-notice knowledge you're not a brain in a vat, but you have I-can-see-them knowledge of your hands, which is typically all you care about.

Now onto Hume. On the one hand, he argues against the possibility of having one particular kind of very demanding knowledge of something. For instance, his argument against induction is basically that we have neither *a priori* nor non-circular *a posteriori* knowledge that the unexperienced will be like the experienced. You "know" it will in a cheaper sense, such as that expectation having predictive and explanatory power, concordance, and so on. But, for whatever reason, Hume takes it as read, even if only by psychological compunction, that natural laws exist in the middle of his anti-miracles argument. *Insofar as* he "knows" of the laws, they have certain implications.

Comment: Well, if I've understood right, you would say that Hume A-knows that natural laws are predictive and B-knows that they are not. Yes? It could work provided it is clear which sense of "know" he is using. Do we get to have an opinion about whether it is appropriate for him to switch contexts? If we do, I would suggest that in this case, it is not. Either way, it makes it difficult to assess arguments.

Comment: @LudwigV There's no one proposition he both knows to be true and knows to be false, even with "knowledge" having multiple senses. Ironically, "predictive" may have a context-dependent meaning in your confusion as well. You must distinguish laws being predictive in the sense Nature obeys them so their predictions are accurate from their being predictive in the sense we know such predictions will be accurate, which subdivides based on the sense of knowledge. (By the way, your use of A and B is reversed relative to my answer.)

Comment: @ J.G. I'm sorry my last reply was so confusing. I think Hume and I are interested in how we can make predictions and know that they are true. Hume does identify a kind of psychological compulsion which he calls custom or habit, but doesn't confuse that with proof. He gives a kind of justification by saying that these predictions are useful. However, he doesn't offer any proof of that, which leaves me nowhere.

Comment: @LudwigV If your question is how his stances can be reconciled in modern terms, we can claim he only refuted one kind of knowledge claim for natural laws but not another. If your question is how Hume would have reconciled them, my guess is he didn't mind arguments with premises which had his confidence but which he would admit he couldn't know were true. The modern option is obviously more satisfying. (Hume does the same thing, by the way, with ethics: he's famous for the is-ought gap, but he also advocated specific ethics, including conservatism.)

Comment: @J. G. It's beginning to look as if there are a number of inconsistencies in Hume's work. This one, between causation and free will and yours in ethics. H'm. But this epistemic contextualism has me confused. He refuted the claim to prove knowledge of natural laws _a priori_. Are you suggesting our psychological compulsion to believe them is a knowledge claim? That seems odd.

Comment: @LudwigV Before we go any further, to be clear, Hume did more then refute _a priori_ knowledge of natural laws; he refuted one flavour - in his view, the only one - of _a posteriori_ knowledge of them. Neither I nor Hume felt psychology means knowledge; then again, premises need only be true, not known. My suggestion is we know of natural laws, just not in the way Hume showed we didn't.

Comment: @ J.G. So how do we know of natural laws? In your view.

Comment: @LudwigV As I said in the answer, _You "know" it will in a cheaper sense, such as that expectation having predictive and explanatory power, concordance, and so on._ See also e.g. [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/induction-problem/#NomoExplSolu).

Comment: You did indeed. Sorry. But Hume doesn't acknowledge any predictive power. See my first quotation (the one from the _Treatise_) in the question. Also, what, exactly is explanatory power? Are you thinking of deductive-nomological explanations? I have a nasty feeling that they may be open to Hume's objections.

Comment: @LudwigV If your question is how the views can be reconciled, I think my answer does that. If your question is how they can be reconciled exclusively with Hume's realizations, without saying anything he'd disagree with, I doubt that can be done. But for the record, I don't accept that Hume's objections dismantle abduction et al.

Comment: Well, your answer seems to me to amount to saying that Hume is going to continue to behave as if nature is uniform in spite of his argument. That would explain the passage on miracles.  Whether it is a viable answer is another question. I'm interested in both Hume's beliefs and with reality.

Comment: @LudwigV His first argument doesn't attack uniformity, but our grounds for believing in it. The gist of much of his philosophy is  we're forced to believe many things, but his skeptical attempt to infer the scope of rationality allows it to defend virtually none of them, so it's unsurprising he feels unable to limit himself to it. He argued it's passions, not reason, that must enjoy primacy. My point is we needn't settle for his approach because knowledge is more pluralistic than he articulated.

Comment: I've been invited to move this discussion to chat and I think we should agree. Otherwise, we'll have to cut it short. So I've agreed. I hope you are ok with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140381/discussion-between-ludwig-v-and-j-g).

Comment: The room is called "Discussion between Ludwig V and J.G."